# Looking for information on a Lego manual I had as a kid

Tags: instructions, design, vintage

I had a lot of Lego when I was younger (in the late 80s/90s). In a flash of nostalgia I recently remembered having a great instructions/ideas book that I loved to read through - I can't remember the number, or even if it was an official instruction manual, all I can remember is that it contained information on a 'line plotter', which used a roll of paper and a few pens to draw lines, which at the time I thought was amazing - I may have even built it.

I've been able to find out some information - it appears that the plotter was built by Larry Page (yes, of Google fame!), and I have also managed to find this picture from the book...

[image: Larry Page's Line Plotter]

Does anybody else have any information on this book? A PDF would be excellent, but any information would be of interest to me.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The book you're looking for is the "Expert Builder Idea Book (8888)". The complete book is available on [Peeron](http://www.peeron.com/cgi-bin/invcgis/scans/8888-1/?ct=1).

Comment: You're welcome. I absolutely loved this book, and was always fascinated by the plotter. I don't think that it is any coincidence that I enjoy a career as a programmer, and would site this model as one of the inspirations behind my vocation. I'm delighted to be reminded of it all.

Comment: Sadly, I'm not certain that the model in the book was by Larry Page. Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Page) says that Page designed his LEGO plotter whilst at University. The Idea Book was published in 1980 when Page would have been about 7 years old. I don't doubt that a prodigious 7-year-old might come up with a clever LEGO design, but I'm not sure that he would be at University by that age.

Comment: I agree. I assume the post in which I read about it probably had the wrong picture (which is the one I've included here), nonetheless, the link you provided was the one I happened to be looking for, thanks again.